# Discrete color ramp in QGIS

Tags: qgis, color-ramp

This seems basic but I am new to QGIS and I can't find how to do it. I have three shape files each with the same attribute. Each shape file is imported into its own layer. Each shape file has attribute values in the range 1-100, but different sub-sets of those values are present in each file.

I want a color ramp where attribute value 62 (for example) has the same color on all three layers, but the colour ramp I am using assigns a different color to value 62 on each layer. I think it is because the range of values in each layer is different. I think my color ramp is a continuous range and not discrete colours tied to a discrete value.

How do I build a ramp where the full range of values is covered and a given value always has the same color on different layers?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @LizT! A quick and simple method could be to create a colour style on the layer which contains the most range of values. Then you can _right-click_ this layer, select `Copy style` and then _right-click_ the other layers and select `Paste style`. Now all your layers would be using the same colour style.

Comment: I suggest you to merge all three layers and set a color ramp for "merged" layer. Copy/paste style of merged layer on three layers as @Joseph stated. In this way, you have the same color ramp for all three layers. Then you can remove "merged" layer.

Comment: Thanks, both these helped, my maps are now consistent. Thanks a lot!